# iOS get distance from point to polyline

Tags: ios, distance, polyline

I would like to calculate the shortest distance between a point and a polyline in iOS application.
What would be the best way to make this?
Is there any built-in method that could help?

Thanks a lot,
Regards.

Comment: Calculate the [distances from each segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line), take their minimum.

Comment: There's no built in method I believe

Comment: @user529758 This algorithm works for infinitive lines, here we have 2 ending points. bobby Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: anyone found a solution to this issue?